# How to select tags that have certain attribute type

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Here's the Thing

I want to crawl only these tags in the full of other messy html

```
<table bgcolor="FFFFFF" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="./index.html?id=subjective&page=2">
                <img src='https://www.dogdrip.net/?module=file&act=procFileDownload&file_srl=224868098&sid=cc8c0afbb679bef6420500988a756054&module_srl=78' style='max-width:180px;max-height:270px' align='absmiddle' title="cutie cat">
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I tried for the first time with CSS selector
selector was

```
#div_article_contents > tr:nth-child(1) > th:nth-child(1) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td > table > tbody > tr > td > a > img
```

but `soup.select('selector')` wasn't works. It output empty list.
I don't know why

Secondly I tried with tag
every  that I want to crawl have specific style
so I tried:

```
soup.select('img[style = fixedstyle]')
```

but it wasn't works. It would be syntax error...

all I want to crawl is
list of href links
and list of img titles

please help me

Comment: `soup.select('img[style=fixedstyle]')` should work. remove extra spaces

Comment: That fixed style is 'max-width:222px;max-height:222px' and it wasn't work now without spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `img` tag has a specific style value you can use what you tried just delete extra spaces:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''
<a href='link'>
    <img src='address' style='max-width:222px;max-height:222px' title='owntitle'>
</a>
<a href='link'>
    <img src='address1' style='max-width:222px;max-height:222px' title='owntitle1'>
</a>
<a href='link'>
    <img src='address2' style='max-width:222px;max-height:222px' title='owntitle2'>
</a>
'''

srcs=[]
titles=[]
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
for img in soup.select('img["style=max-width:222px;max-height:222px"]'):
    srcs.append(img['src'])
    titles.append(img['title'])
print(srcs)
print(titles)
```

Other wise you can start with the `a` tag and get down to the `img` like this:

```
for a in soup.select('a'):
    srcs.append(a.select_one('img')['src'])
    titles.append(a.select_one('img')['title'])
print(srcs)
print(titles)
```

Comment: I probably write something wrong.... There are too many <a> with <img> inside. So determinant is style only. Anyway thank you for your help

Comment: I wrote on reply of main post, fixed style is 'max-width:222px;max-height:222px' and it wasn't work with select[]

Comment: soupsieve.util.SelectorSyntaxError: Malformed attribute selector at position 3
  line 1:
img[style=max-width:222px;max-height:222px]

error returned. that is what I want to explain. sorry for bad english post

Comment: can you post part of the real html that you want to scrap?

Comment: I edited main post. these code are actual html code

Comment: please note that the style you have in the real code is not the same to the one you posted before. `soup.select('img[style="max-width:180px;max-height:270px"]')`

Comment: Number doesn't matter because if it has no syntax error then it will output empty list. But it has error and I don't know what is wrong

Comment: Try to run the style value with quotes. like I posted in my last comment.